# How to concat strings in for loop with snprintf or similar function (C)?

Tags: c, http-headers, printf, string-concatenation, c-strings

I have the following code, which is my attempt to make a single string containing the stored HTTP header fields:

```
typedef struct _header {
    char* name;
    char* value;
} header;

const header headers[] = {
    { "Content-Type", "text/html" },
    { "Server", "testServer" }
};

int headerStringSize = sizeof(char) * 1024 + 1;
char* headerString = malloc(headerStringSize);
int i, headersLength = sizeof(headers) / sizeof(headers[0]);
for (i = 0; i < headersLength; ++i) {
    header h = headers[i];
    snprintf(headerString, headerStringSize, "%s: %s\r\n", h.name, h.value);
}
```

However, it doesn't work as `snprintf` simply overwrites the contents of `headerString` on each iteration, rather than appending at the correct char index. I am used to higher-level languages than C, so my problems are entirely down to my own ignorance. I would, therefore, greatly appreciate it if someone could show me the best way to achieve what I want.

Comment: Your variable names are confusing .

Comment: You might like to have look at `strcpy()` and `strcat()`.

Comment: `headerString[0]=0;`before the loop and `snprintf(headerString + strlen(headerString), ....` in the loop.

Comment: @ameyCU Okay, feel free to tell me how I could name them better.

Comment: @mch Thank you very much, that's the fix I needed! Even though it's only short, feel free to write it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should initialize your string:

```
headerString[0]=0;
```

before the loop.

Now you can calculate the end of the string and give `snprintf` a pointer to the end of the string:

```
snprintf(headerString + strlen(headerString), headerStringSize - strlen(headerString), "%s: %s\r\n", h.name, h.value);
```

Also note the changed maximum length parameter. You should also add a check on the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: There is no buffer overflow protection with this code. Because the second argument of snprintf is unsigned so if strlen(headerString) > headerStringSize then headerStringSize - strlen(headerString) will underflow and be cast to a big unsigned number. In this case snprintf will happily create a buffer overflow.

Comment: @leszek.hanusz if you do only this, your szenario cannot happen, the maximum value of `strlen(headerString)` is `headerStringSize - 1`, in this case the `snprintf` will not do anything.

Comment: indeed, a buffer overflow in this case can only happen if there was already another buffer overflow before...